# Can I have an onclick event on a imagemap area element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, area, imagemap

I would like to put an onclick event on an area element. Here is my setup:

```
<img id="image" src="wheel.png" width="2795" height="2795" usemap="#Map" >
    <map name="Map">
    <area class="blue" onclick="myFunction()" shape="poly" coords="2318,480,1510,1284" href="#">
</map>
```

I have tried 2 different ways to have an onclick event. Firstly i tried this:

```
$(".blue").click( function(event){
    alert('test');
});
```

I have also tried this:

```
function myFunction() {
    alert('test');
}
```

Neither of the above work. Do area elements support the above, or do they only support having a href?

Comment: Which value do you need to get ? also, you've an extra quote on `"2318,480,1510,1284""` ?

Comment: The zone that you try to click is not clickable! :)

Comment: is this default behaviour?

Comment: @PedroLobito i need to call a javascript function on click, this extra quote was a typo

Comment: that's it ?! you don't need the coords the user clicked on ?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Pay attention:

1. Attribute href is obligatory, without it the area-tag does nothing!
2. To add a click event, you'll need to block default href.

---

Your code should start as follows:

```
$(".blue").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    /*
       your code here
    */
});
```

[Live example here.](http://jsfiddle.net/bL5rgstg/)

Comment: That's a great answer... But may I know what I need to change to display image on click ? Kindly refer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34046331/display-image-in-a-popup-same-window-onclick-of-a-particular-area-on-the-base

Comment: In HTML 5, href may be omitted: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/area

Answer (score 11):

Its the shape that's the problem. Your code has set shape equal to polygon but only has 4 points in the coordinates attribute. You need to set shape to rectangle instead.

Set shape="rect" like this:

```html
<img id="image" src="wheel.png" width="2795" height="2795" usemap="#Map" >
    <map name="Map">
    <area class="blue" onclick="myFunction()" shape="rect" coords="2318,480,1510,1284" href="#">
</map>
```

Comment: This actually answered the OP's question, and didn't need jquery.

Answer (score 3):

Use a class for all elements you want to listen on, and optionally an attribute for behavior:

```
<map name="primary">
  <area shape="circle" coords="75,75,75" class="popable" data-text="left circle text">
  <area shape="circle" coords="275,75,75" class="popable" data-text="right circle text">
</map>
<img usemap="#primary" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="350 x 150 pic">
<div class='popup hidden'></div>
```

Then add your event listeners to all elements in the class:

```
const popable = document.querySelectorAll('.popable');
const popup = document.querySelector('.popup');
let lastClicked;

popable.forEach(elem => elem.addEventListener('click', togglePopup));

function togglePopup(e) {
  popup.innerText = e.target.dataset.text;

  // If  clicking something else, first restore '.hidden' to popup so that toggle will remove it.
  if (lastClicked !== e.target) {
    popup.classList.add('hidden');
  }
  popup.classList.toggle('hidden');
  lastClicked = e.target;  // remember the target
}
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/weird_error/pen/xXPNOK

Comment: When having a **href** this needs `e.preventDefault()`

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comments, you just need this:

```
$("#image").click( function(){
 alert("clicked");
//your code here
});
```

---

Demo:

http://codepen.io/tuga/pen/waBQBZ

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple one:

```html
<area class="blue" onclick="alert('test');" shape="poly" coords="2318,480,1510,1284" href="#">
```

Or for any other code:

```html
<area class="blue" onclick="//JavaScript Code//" shape="poly" coords="2318,480,1510,1284" href="#">
```

Comment: You have added a snippet but without content so nothing "to see" is render, maybe you can modify html code to exactly view running the snippet what you did

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
<img  src="wheel.png" width="2795" height="2795" alt="Weels" usemap="#map">

<map name="map">
 <area shape="poly" coords="2318,480,1510,1284" alt="otherThing" href="anotherFile">
</map>
```

You souldn't want to add `onClick` events on area, documentation :

> The  tag defines an area inside an image-map (an image-map is an image with clickable areas).

Edit : your coords are a bit weird since its supposed to the couples of each vertices (so right now, your polygon is a line)

Comment: But i would like to call some javascript onclick. Is this not achievable?

Comment: Sure just add an id on the area you want to click on and use `$("#id").on("click", function(e){    
   //DoSTG
});`

Answer (score 0):

I found this question by @TimorEranAV 
[HTML map that displays text instead of linking to a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46574216/html-map-that-displays-text-instead-of-linking-to-a-url)
and was marked as duplicate, but i think what he was expecting is this,

```
<html>
<head>
 <title> Program - Image Map</title>
</head>
<body>


 <img src="new.png" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap">

<map name="planetmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" href="sun.htm" alt="Sun" title = "Sun">
  <area shape="rect" coords="82,0,100,126" href="mercur.htm" alt="Mercury" title = "Mercury">

</map>

</body>
</html>
```

Here the title tag gives the opportunity to add a hover text(tip) to the image map.