# Interactive JPG or PDF

Tags: image, user-interface, interactive, imagemap

So I am taking a remote internship and have been tasked with transferring a JPG or a PDF of an image and making it interactive so users can click on their choices, then at the end it determines an answer based on the choices you chose.

I am fairly new at web design and originally thought about creating an image map of the object and figuring out a way to store the selected choices.

Is this even possible? Is the owner of the company out of her mind trying to get interns with no web design experience or guidance to complete this task? If not, what is the best method for completing something like this? Would a PDF be better. Mind you there aren't even real results for this "quiz" yet.

[Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6bFE9_FVRJ1WlNJb1RyYjBUMzQ) is the image they want me/us to make interactive. Any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciative.

Comment: Transferring a JPG from where to where? Why? How? JPEGs aren't interactive - they are pictures. What is the *"it"* that returns a result? A result based on what? Where does it return the results to?

Comment: Does it have to be a single image or could it be an image made up of multiple separate images?

Comment: Mark: I know JPEG are images, the owner wants to the the image I added above and make it interactive, so a user can select their specific answers. They are trying to some up with some sort of "results" based around the answer choices. At the end of the quiz, there would be a "submit" or "results" button to display the result.

Comment: tcasey: She would like for it to be a single image. That's why I was leaning towards creating image maps for the answer choices, assigning them to a variable with a value. Then taking the selected values, adding them together and based on the range you would get a result.

Comment: Maybe you mean this? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp

Comment: Yes, I was thinking to create something like that, but how would I store information from the map tags into variables? So when an item is clicked/selected, a variable and value is stored. Then to recall the values and total them up to display a result.

Comment: Use an HTML "map" and add an "onclick" event... http://stackoverflow.com/a/29921981/2836621