# How to click using Javascript that uses map tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have a gif image on my webpage that looks as below :

[image]

The html code generated is shown below :

[image]

How do i write a script in javascript that trigger click on home or help or signoff page? Please help

EDIT :

I am very new to JavaScript and this website was developed by client developers. I am trying to automate the business process using Robotic Process Automation tool called UiPath.

One of the feature in UiPath is injecting JavaScript on a webpage which can be used to fill in the User-forms and navigate to different screen.

Comment: are you using jQuery?

Comment: href tag is there,it will navigate you there if you click. If you want you can use onclick to call a javascript function

Comment: Could you provide generated HTML, rather than image? And, out of curiosity, why map for links? And, shouldn't this work without javascript, too?

Comment: use `$("area[alt='home']").click()` if you are using jQuery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can i have an onclick event on a imagemap area element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29921696/can-i-have-an-onclick-event-on-a-imagemap-area-element)

Comment: -1 Please provide code that you have produced to show that you have had an attempt so that we can help you on where to go from there. This isn't a tutorial website. Also JavaScript and Java are not the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) function of javascript.

```
document.querySelectorAll('area[alt="Home"]').click = function(){
   window.location.href = "your path";
}
```

Same you can apply for other also.