# is it possible to use image map in <a> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I’m trying to use an image map in `<a>` tag. It has worked in chrome but not hasn’t worked in IE.
Is it okay to use an image map in `<a>` tag?

Here is my code:

```
<div class="planner_banner">
        <a href="xxx">
            <img src="xxx" usemap="#planner_banner_map" border="0">
            <map name="planner_banner_map">
                <area shape="rect" coords="243, 1, 272, 30" 
                onclick="$('.planner_banner').hide();return false;"/>
            </map>
        </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can i have an onclick event on a imagemap area element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29921696/can-i-have-an-onclick-event-on-a-imagemap-area-element)

Comment: Having a secondary link within a more global one is bad practice from an accessibility point of view so you probably want to avoid doing that anyway

Comment: Also, I guess you mean in a `<a>` tag, and not just 'In a tag' (in any tag). Please edit your question if that's the cause, for the sake of clarity, not everybody can read between the lines ;-)

Comment: yes I wanted to say <a> tag. sorry for confusion. thanks for your advice Capsule :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it okay to use an image map in `<a>` tag?

No. See [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/textlevel-semantics.html#the-a-element):

> The a element … Content model: Transparent, but **there must be no interactive content** or a element descendants.

And [interactive content](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#interactive-content-2) is defined as:

> a (if the href attribute is present) audio (if the controls attribute is present) button details embed iframe **img (if the usemap attribute is present)** input (if the type attribute is not in the Hidden state) label select textarea video (if the controls attribute is present)

Answer (score -1):

Add `#` before map name

```
<map name="#planner_banner_map">
  <area shape="rect" coords="243, 1, 272, 30" 
  onclick="$('.planner_banner').hide();return false;"/>
</map>
```